# Media Query not working on Iphones (Safari and Chrome)

Tags: html, css

I am creating a page with a button and inside this there is an arrow and text. So, the idea here is for the arrow and the text to be side by side, where the text is on the left and the arrow on the right.

The problem is: the css that i'm applying for responsive works well in my android phone, but it's not working on iPhones (and not working on Safari and Chrome inside the iPhone).

The button:

[image]

I have tried to change the sizing unit (from vw to percentage), in case it was not compatible with Safari browsers (that would be also weird) and tested again. the problem is still there and everything is okay on android.

The CSS code outside the Media Query:

```
.subs_arrow {
width: 13vw;
height: 5.5vh;
vertical-align: sub;
}

.subs_text {
 font-size: 9vw;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is Media Query CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 451px) {

.subs_arrow {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
  vertical-align: sub;
}

.subs_text {
  font-size: 85%;
}

}
```

Viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<button class="lp6_button">
    <span id="form_pin_code_add_btn_send" class="subs_text">إشترك</span>
    <img src="./img/white-right-arrow-md.png" class="subs_arrow">
</button>
```

What is the solution here?

Comment: Do you have meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your code? Also it seems strange that you are using vh units for font-sizing...

Comment: @Andrija
Look at my code. I have updated the question and added the viewport i had already in my code.

Comment: I am not able to test it on iOS now but make sure the img tag is set to inline and try to set `white-space: no-wrap` on the button element.

Comment: @Andrija I have a fiddle with your solution inside `.subs_arrow` class. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/3pd9phuj/

Comment: Sorry but as I said, I can't test it on iPhone now. It just seems to me that you are mixing too many units and style rules in that simple button :) Try to make it more simple. That way you can catch bugs more easily too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because iPhones (especially older ones) can have smaller screen sizes than most Android phones. Therefore, the text can be pushed down in order to avoid smushing. For your case, I would use flexbox instead of the approach you're taking.

```
.yourentirebutton {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
```

Comment: but why is not working on either browsers? Safari and Chrome?

Comment: @Timmy try flexbox ^

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your `head` tag. You can read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: Actually i have the viewport code. Here: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`